# Postgresql query with multiple conditions per row

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I'm probably down the wrong path but here's what I need to achieve:

Given the following `products_table`:

| brand | color | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GUCCI | BLUE | NEW |
| CHANEL | RED | NEW |
| GUCCI | RED | NEW |

I'm trying to say the following:

> Select any product `COLOR` which doesn't offer a `GUCCI` brand having a status of `NEW`

**The expected outcome in this case would be 0, since both `RED` and `BLUE` are color variations offered by `NEW` `GUCCI` products.**

My naive effort to solve this has so far resulted in this:

```sql
SELECT
    color
FROM
    products_table
WHERE brand != 'GUCCI' AND status == 'NEW'
```

This above however returns 'CHANEL, RED, NEW' which is not the desired output since `RED` is already being offered by `GUCCI` with status `NEW`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise it's perfect, but would the `except` clause work?

```
SELECT distinct color
FROM
  products_table p1
except
select color
from products_table p2
where
  brand = 'GUCCI' and
  status = 'NEW'
```

Also this is probably not super efficient...  if your table has a lot of records, there are better ways to do it, but this is scalable and easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to do exactly what I need it to do!